# Regex to match character string in filename

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make a list of all PHP files within a directory that have a specific character string (in my case a datestamp) at the beginning of the name AND a specific string ".php" at the end.  My date is being passed in as a variable ($SearchDate).  I have already successfully set up the PHP script to read in a full list of files from my directory, and was just trying to use preg_match to filter the list for me.  Unfortunatly I am a complete failure at RegEx even having tried repeatedly with [this cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/).

Here is what I have that is generating errors and no results:

```
$SearchDate = '2013-02'; //example for february of 2013

if(preg_match('#^('.$SearchDate.')+[:graph:]{1}(\.(pdf))#', $file)) {
   //do something
}
```

I also tried:

```
preg_match('#^\Q'.$SearchDate.'\E+[:graph:]{1}\Q.pdf\E#', $file)
```

My filenames look like this:

> 2013-02-fileNameMightBeAlphaOr1234567890.pdf

The errors I am getting look like this:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: POSIX
>   named classes are supported only within a class at offset 5 in
>   /home/directory/myfile.php on line 26

Comment: Why not just `"#^$SearchDate#"`?  Anyway, your specific error is refering to the fact that `[:graph:]` doesn't match anything on its own.  It needs to be in a character class:  `[[:graph:]]`  But really, I don't think this regular expression will work properly anyway.

Comment: Though, you could just as easily use strpos (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) with a line like `if (strpos($file, $SearchDate) === 0){ /*Found it!*/ }`

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan adding extra brackets around graph did get rid of my error messages...now i just have to figure out why it is not matching my string :-)  This is a good start.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not matching your string because you're only matching one character (`{1}`) and you're trying to repeat the search Date.  Try the regex I gave earlier, or this one, if you're insistent on matching the whole filename: `'#^'.$SearchDate.'[[:graph:]]+?\.pdf$#'` - though I'm not quite sure you need all that extra, if you're just making sure that it starts with `$StartDate`.  If it's just that and .pdf:  try `'#^'.$SearchDate.'.*\.pdf'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to also be checking that it ends with ".pdf" so I basically
>   need the start and end of the filename and don't care what happens in
>   the middle.

If that's the case then following regex should work for you:

```
if(preg_match('#^' . $SearchDate . '.*?\.pdf$#', $file)) {
   //do something
}
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/h66GY0

Comment: So much simpler than what I was trying...and it works great.  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

this simple regexp should work

```
preg_match('/^'.$SearchDate.'/', $file);
```

Comment: I need to also be checking that it ends with ".pdf" so I basically need the start and end of the filename and don't care what happens in the middle.

Comment: preg_match('/^'.$SearchDate.'.+?\.pdf$/', $file);

Answer (score 0):

add `{` and `}` to your graph...like

```
     preg_match('#^('.$SearchDate.')+[{:graph:}]{1}(\.(pdf))#', $file)
```

Comment: This is similar to what @FrankieTheKneeMan suggested...and it does get rid of the error messages...but it still is not matching any of my filenames.